# nginx isn't generating any php-fpm.sock anyone have any ideas why?

Tags: sockets, nginx, php

I have recently built a new web server using the (LEMP) method and it's all running good, I also installed Varnish and phpMyAdmin into the lemp install.

I added unix: /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock to the location / {

Then I told www.conf to listen to /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock

however nginx isn't generating any sockets to the /var/run/php-fpm folder.

All the services are running correctly and I can access the default webpage at my-ip but trying to access anything else i.e my-ip/anythingelse gives me 502 bad gateway because it's not finding the socket.

Does anyone know what could be the cause and a fix?

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
    worker_processes  4;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    pid        /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  60;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

index   index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen  127.0.0.1:8080;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
}


server {
listen       443;

ssl                  on;
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

ssl_session_timeout  5m;

ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

location / {
root   html;
index  index.html index.htm;
}
location ~* ^/phpMyAdmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ { root /usr/share/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
}
}
```

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2519/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4010/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4046/varnishd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3988/php-fpm: maste 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2711/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38350           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1559/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1362/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4050/varnishd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4010/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1361/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3500/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2519/master
tcp6       0      0 :::33209                :::*                    LISTEN      1559/rpc.statd
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1362/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1361/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      3500/cupsd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59473           0.0.0.0:*                           1559/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           1362/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           726/chronyd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           726/chronyd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:679             0.0.0.0:*                           1362/rpcbind
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:888           0.0.0.0:*                           1559/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42032           0.0.0.0:*                           685/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           685/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                1362/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                726/chronyd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                726/chronyd
udp6       0      0 :::679                  :::*                                1362/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::60779                :::*                                1559/rpc.statd
[root@localhost ~]#

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your nginx configuration.

Comment: php-fpm should create the socket, not nginx

Comment: Ahh, though it was the nginx service. either way it's not being created lol

Comment: Check if php-fpm is running, with `sudo service php5-fpm status`. If it's not running, do a `sudo service php5-fpm start`. And still, please [edit] your question to show us your nginx configuration.

Comment: no such file or directory. I don't have php5-fpm it's just php-fpm ?

Comment: One issue is that you're using a non-absolute path as root (`html`). Also, in your question you wrote that you added the socket to the location `/`, but I don't see that in your configuration.

Comment: When do you get the message 'no such file or directory'? Please be precise.

Comment: html is the directory where the web server sits

I used a tutorial to set up my web server so it's identicle to their setup. and the socket is under    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;

Comment: I got the message 'no such file or directory' when i ran systemctl status php5-fpm.service

Comment: You should use an absolute path for your root folder. Also, in your question you wrote that you added the socket to the location /, but I don't see that in your configuration.

Comment: The socket is in both location ~ \.php$ { fastcgi_pass unix:

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you if you ignore my hints. Here are the things I can think of right now: 1. look in the logs; 2. your index lines don't have index.php (though maybe that's correct for your setup); 3. your socket location may be incorrect - I have /var/run/php5-fpm.sock. Since you don't have index.php as an index, the fastcgi_index parameter doesn't have any effect: requests to folders will not be handled by FastCGI anyway, as this is only used in the \.php location block. Either handle everything with FastCGI, or put index.php in the index directive. Good luck!

Comment: You haven't gave me any hints, I made the path absolute for html, I have checked the log but it just say's cannot connect to upstream (no such file or directory) I followed it from a tutorial. And I'm using php-fpm NOT php5-fpm this is my first time using linux and lemp. I'm used to windows and wamp but due to my server load dramatically increasing i decided to try a faster web server.

Comment: The problem is the .sock file isn't being generated so i assume it may be a permission? 

It's to my understanding that nginx.conf is basically the same as wamp's httpd-vhosts however i'm not entirely sure on how to implement php into nginx.

Comment: This is the error i get, 2015/01/26 19:42:28 [error] 5356#0: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost" any ideas?

Comment: And you're sure that php-fpm is running? Then check in /var/run if there's anything with a name like 'php'. You can also do a `sudo netstat -ulntap` to check that php-fpm isn't listening on port 9000 instead of on a socket, that's the default in some configurations.

Comment: yup, 100% positive php-fpm is running, the folder is there /var/run/php-fpm it's just not generating a .sock file. If you look at my edit I have included my netstat printout. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue and figured out why it wasn't creating the socket...

I thought I would take extra precautions with the files I was editing and created backups in the folders... Well because of this it was including the .conf's twice which is why it was still using 127.0.0.1:9000 even though I told it to use /var/run/php-fmp/php-fpm.sock ... lesson learned - (put backups in a separate root folder.

Have another wee issue now though. *2 FastCGI sent in stderr "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream?

Thank you for a push in the right direction... Had you not of mentioned to do a netstat I probably wouldn't have thought about the backup files.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is using a socket, while php-fpm listens on port 9000. You can use `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` instead in nginx. You can also configure php-fpm to listen on a socket instead following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/114086/125111).